# Where can I download older versions of Oracle Instantclient?

Tags: oracle

Version 10.2 is linked from here, but I need 10.1.  Any clues where to get older copies of the instantclient packages?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link that lets you download 10.1.0.5:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

This particular link is for 32-bit Windows.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bryce... I was trying to download the Mac 10.1, but this link helpfully revealed that all versions are put on the download page, so I was able to figure out that the version I was having a hard time locating was never built for mac!